# Snackbar with setOnLongClickListener

Tags: android, onlongclicklistener, androiddesignsupport, android-snackbar, snackbar

I want to be able to show a snackbar when a button is long pressed. I have a FAB that behaves perfectly but this won't work. (Ignore the orderCounter and +100. That is another part of the long press.)

```
Button plusButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_plus);
    plusButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            orderCounter += 100;  // orderCounter = orderCounter + 100;
            showOrderCounter();

            return true;
        }
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "+100", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```

The app loads and works perfectly expect that this specific snackbar won't show. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the `Snackbar` into the `onLongClick`.

```
public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        orderCounter += 100;  // orderCounter = orderCounter + 100;
        showOrderCounter();
        Snackbar.make(v, "+100", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .setAction("Action", null).show();
        return true;
}
```